# Confirm beforeunload in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, onbeforeunload, confirm

i know that there are hundreds of questions like: "How can i prevent close event in electron" or something like that.
After implementing a confirmation box (electron message box) in the `beforeunload` event i was able to close my app and cancel the close event. Since the dev tools are always open, i didn't recognize that it doesn't work while the dev tools are closed...

```
window.onbeforeunload = e =>
{           
    // show a message box with "save", "don't save", and "cancel" button
    let warning = remote.dialog.showMessageBox(...) 

    switch(warning)
    {
        case 0:
            console.log("save");
            return;
        case 1:
            console.log("don't save");
            return;
        case 2:
            console.log("cancel");
            return false;
            // e.returnValue = "false";
            // e.returnValue = false;
    }
};
```

So, when the dev tools are opened, i can close the app with saving, without saving and cancel the event.
When the dev tools are closed, the cancel button doesn't work anymore.

Btw.:

```
window.onbeforeunload = e =>
{           
    return false;
    alert("foo");
};
```

will cancel the close event and obviously wouldn't show the message (doesn't matter if dev tools are open or closed)

```
window.onbeforeunload = e =>
{           
    alert("foo");
    return false;
};
```

will cancel the close event after pressing ok if dev tools are open and will close the app after pressing ok if dev tools are closed

Intentionally i'm using the synchronous api of the message box and while i'm writing this question i figured out that a two windowed app (`new remote.BrowserWindow()`) will behave exactly like with the dev tools.

Has anyone an idea how i can resolve this problem?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're running into a [known problem in Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7977).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of `onbeforeunload` prefer working with the event `close`. From this event, you'll be able to catch the closing event before the whole closure process is completed (event `closed`). With `close`, you'll be able to take the control and stop whenever you need the completion of the closure.

This is possible when you create your BrowserWindow, preferably in the main process:

```
// Create the browser window.
window = new BrowserWindow({});

// Event 'close'
window.on('close', (e) => {
    // Do your control here
    if (bToStop) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})

// Event 'closed'
window.on('closed', (e) => {
    // Fired only if you didn't called e.preventDefault(); above!
})
```

In addition, be aware that the function `e.preventDefault()` is spreading in the whole code. If you need to be back to the natural behaviour of Electron, you need to toggle the variable `e.defaultPrevented` to `false`.

Actually, it seems `e.preventDefault()` function is handling the variable `e.defaultPrevented` to `true` until any change on it.

Comment: Thanks @Jerome, now i listen to the close event in the main process and call `e.preventDefault();`. Additionally the main process sends an event to the renderer. There i will show the dialog and check some other stuff. If the user doesn't click on cancel, i will exit the app by calling `remote.app.exit();`, so the dialog wouldn't pop up again.

Comment: One big problem was, that there are multiple different events like closing the app ("x" / "exit" in menu) or restarting it ("restart" in menu or pressing F5 in dev tools). So i wasn't able to use the method, because i didn't actually know, which event occured. Now i removed the restart events (usually the user wouldn't open the dev tools anyway).

Comment: Well, to avoid such issue, I was keeping track of the state of the window on each of my events. Proceeding this way allowed me to know if the `'close'`event was fired due to my code (e.f. events, buttons, functions...) or due to "X" button of the window pressed by the user. Feel free to provide updated code.

Comment: This worked fine for me on macOS but was ignored on windows

Comment: It was working initially on Windows too! This is probably due to change in the code of Electron.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will help someone with similar needs as i had, i have a react app wrapped in an electron app, the react app is agnostic to electron and can also run in the browser and the requirements i had was to show the default browser prompt, the infamous `Leave Site?` alert.

In the browser this is easy, for example with react i just do this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   window.onbeforeunload = promptOnProjectLeave ? () => true : undefined;
    return () => {
        window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
    }
}, [promptOnProjectLeave]);
```

Which will show the default browser `Leave Site?` prompt, but in electron this will only prevent the window from being closed without any action prompt asking you if you are sure, so my approach was a mix of this post and another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426745/electron-remove-beforeunload-event-listeners).

This is the solution

```js
mainWindow.webContents.on('will-prevent-unload', (event) => {
    const options = {
        type: 'question',
        buttons: ['Cancel', 'Leave'],
        message: 'Leave Site?',
        detail: 'Changes that you made may not be saved.',
    };
    const response = dialog.showMessageBoxSync(null, options)
    if (response === 1) event.preventDefault();
});
```

This will allow me to use `window.onbeforeunload` in my react code as i would in the browser, in the browser i will get the default browser prompt and in electron i will get a message box :)

This is my first time working with electron so might be some ways to improve this but either way hope this helps someone, i know it would have helped me when i started with this task.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

As I mentioned above in the comments of the accepted answer, the `preventDefault` was ignored on Windows. To be precise, I had it placed in the callback of a native electron dialog that opened when the user closed the app.

Therefore I have implemented a different approach:

```
let close: boolean = false    

win.on('close', (ev: any) => {

  if (close === false) {
    ev.preventDefault()

    dialog.showMessageBox({
      type: 'warning',
      buttons: ['Cancel', 'Ok'],
      title: 'Do not forget to safe your changes',
      cancelId: 0,
      defaultId: 1,
      noLink: true
    }).then((val) => {

      if (val.response === 0) {
        // Cancel the close process
      } else if (win) {
        close = true
        app.quit()
      }
    })
  }

})
```

Comment: I think the problem is really that you are using the async messagebox. So thread will continue down the road not hitting e.preventDefault even the messageBox is showing, and the window/app/messagebox will close before the user can act. Note that if you use async version of the dialog.showMessageBox, then in the version I'm on, the window will close because the thread continues and e.preventDefault has not yet been set in the async call. So for this to work all you need to use the Sync version: the call must be: ....dialog.showMessageBoxSync( .... Then you dont need the boolean approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `'pagehide'` event. It seems to be working fine for electron apps. It works slightly different from `'beforeunload'` as it can't prevent closing window/tab, but if you only need to do something before the page is closed(send some async request with `navigator.sendBeacon()`, etc) then this event might suit your needs.

You can read more info about it [here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/page-lifecycle-api/#the-unload-event), [here](https://tech.trivago.com/post/2020-11-17-exploringthepagevisibilityapifordetectin/) and in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event)

Example of usage:

```
window.addEventListener('pagehide', () => {
    window.navigator.sendBeacon(url, data);
}
```