# Electron.js prevent windows close conditionally

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to ask user if he really want to close an electron app.

Accordingly [to docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-close) - I've tried:

```
window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
  const answer = confirm('Do you want to close the application?');
  e.returnValue = answer;
  if (answer) { window.close(); }
};
```

But my app still closes no matter what user choose.
How to prevent close an Electron app conditionally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess, I have an answer.
It shouldn't be called in renderer process.
Instead we should use mainWindow in **main process** for such operation and 'close' lifecycle method, which will be called right before closing.

```
this.mainWindow.on('close', (e) => {
  const choice = this.dialog.showMessageBox(
    this.mainWindow,
    {
      type: 'question',
      buttons: ['Yes', 'No, hang on', 'third option'],
      title: 'Confirm your actions',
      message: 'Do you really want to close the application?'
    }
  );
  console.log('CHOICE: ', choice);
  if (choice > 0) e.preventDefault();
});
```

choice const will return an answer from buttons array, so 'Yes' will be as confirm and for other options we can prevent actions.

NOTE: I've pasted with `this.` from my code, but, obviously `mainWindow` is your `BrowserWindow` instance and `this.dialog` is `electron.dialog` that imported from `import electron from 'electron';`

Comment: This was ignored for me on Windows but worked on macOS

Comment: I posted a working answer below a similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63813373/6213524

Comment: Note that if you use async version of the dialog.showMessageBox, then in the version I'm on, the window will close because the thread continues and e.preventDefault has not yet been set in the async call. So for this to work you need to use the Sync version: Code like the example, but the call must be: ....dialog.showMessageBoxSync( ....

Comment: Another little note is that if you have more windows, then these will close no matter what. You can write on('close' ... handlers for them as well and control from main window (with some boolean vars) if the event handler on the other windows will call preventDefault or not. I had to do this to avoid my worker window was shutdown, even if the user cancelled closing the app/mainWindow

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally close window in Electron ^15, do:

```js
win.on('close', async e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const { response } = await dialog.showMessageBox(win, {
    type: 'question',
    title: '  Confirm  ',
    message: 'Are you sure that you want to close this window?',
    buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
  })

  response === 0 && win.destroy()
})
```