# How to handle 'Are you sure?' popup in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron, puppeteer

I am creating a bot in Electron.js that posts to a website. When it makes a selection, the page navigates and submits a form. I'm pretty sure it's firing a beforeunload event and asking the user for confirmation. When I tried to set

window.onbeforeunload = ()=>{}

it didn't throw an error but it still continued to ask if I was sure.

snippet of the page html,

```
<form id="repoststore" method="post" action="https://some-navigation.com">
<select style="width: 100%; display: none;" name="sid" id="sid" onchange="setConfirmStore()">
<option value="-1">-- Repost store item --</option>
...
</form>
```

Could this confirm dialog box be caused by the 'setConfirmStore()' function that appears to trigger onchange? If so, is there a way I can prevent this?

I am using electron for the application and Puppeteer for the automation.

Thank you for your time and expertise!

Comment: I tried to set `window.onbeforeunload = ()=>{}` on websites where there's confirmation popup, and it worked. Have you checked the `close` event? [Confirm beforeunload in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827709/confirm-beforeunload-in-electron)

Comment: I hadn't tried, but after trying it didn't work, it just prevented the app window from closing. I think the confirm might be coming from the 'setConfirmStore()' function that's called in the onchange. for the select. I'm gonna do some more digging in the html